# How to find a mean for only some rows in a table?

Tags: r, aggregate, subset, mean

I am new to R and doing some basic things. I wonder how can I find mean for only some rows. For example, how can I find mean weight for korgi only? (There are actually 100 rows instead of 8 and rows 1-50 are korgi) I tried `korgiweight <-aggregate(mytabledata[1:50], list(mytabledata$Weight(kg), mean)` But it says 'undefined columns selected' Thanks.

`**Breed      Weight(kg)**
Korgi      10 
korgi      11
korgi      10.5
korgi      12
husky      20
husky      24
husky      26
husky      25`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calculate the mean by group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11562656/calculate-the-mean-by-group)

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to calculate grouped means. The one you have been trying to do is via `aggregate`. It works like this:

```
aggregate(weight ~ species, data = df, mean)
  species weight
1   Korgi   18.8
2     XYZ   17.9
```

If you want to compute the mean only for a certain range of rows, you need to subset either the dataframe or both variables on that range:

```
aggregate(weight ~ species, data = df[1:10,], mean)
# or:
aggregate(weight[1:10] ~ species[1:10], data = df, mean)

  species[1:10] weight[1:10]
1         Korgi         18.8
```

A related function is `tapply`, which applies a function, here `mean`, to a table:

```
tapply(df$weight, df$species, mean)
Korgi   XYZ 
 18.8  17.9
```

Illustrative data:

```
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(species = c(rep("Korgi", 10), rep("XYZ", 10)),
                 weight = sample(10:25, 20, replace = T))
```

Comment: On SO it is customary to express gratitude by clicking the upward arrow in the upper left corner of the answer to indicate that the answer was useful and/or to click the tick in the  corner to indicate that you accept the answer as the one that solved your problem best.

Answer (score 0):

You can do :

```
korgiweight <- mean(df$Weight.kg.[df$Breed == 'korgi'], na.rm = TRUE)
```